# Working on ABN is that countable as experience for migration purposes?

Tags: resident-permit, australia

I am working full time on ABN (Australia Business Number) as a chef, will this be considered in my experience or I have to work on TFN (Tax File Number) only to claim experience points.

Comment: I randomly guessed what country you're asking about, feel free to correct the tag if I'm wrong

Comment: Thanks mate... yes it was abt Australia

Comment: Like @littleadv, I did a bit of guessing and I assume the question may be clearer to people more familiar with Australia. It would still be good idea to add some details: Experience points for what? A Skilled Independent visa? Working on TFN means as an employee, correct?